# How to prove the equation $\cos x=2x$ has only one solution?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Show that the equation $\cos x=2x$ has only one solution, $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

consider $f(x) = \cos x - 2x$

i)prove that $f$ is strictly decreasing.

ii) find $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1) \lt 0$ and $f(x_2) \gt 0$.

are we done?

Comment: No i still can't solve it. Can you help me a little further please?

Comment: i) says $f$ is injective . So if $f$ take zero, then it will be only once. ii) says indeed $f$ will assume zero at some point. Use intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can see that $cosx=2x$ has solution for a $x_0\in (0,\pi/4)$ and that for $x\in (0,\pi/4)$ we have that $f(x)=cosx $ is 1-1 and so does $g(x)=2x$. So the solution in $(0,\pi /4)$ is unique. Now, for $x\geq \pi/4$ we have that $g(x)\geq \pi/2>1\geq f(x)=cosx$ and this means that they don't have another same point in $\Bbb R$.